# how can I skip two numbers and then get the next three numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

For a given range of numbers, how can I skip two numbers and then get the next three numbers?

e.g. For the range 0..20

0, 1, **2**, **3**, **4**, 5, 6, **7**, **8**, **9**, 10, 11, **12**, **13**, **14**, 15, 16, **17**, **18**, **19**, 20

```
for (let list = 0; list < 100; list++) {
  console.log(list);
}
```

I need to get this type of result:

> 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14....

Comment: "*I need to get this type of list*" - and...? What type of list is that? What have you tried, where did you get stuck? What calculations have you attempted?

Comment: I want to count from 1 to 100. I getting this list

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9......

result should be = [don't need 0, 1] 2,3,4 [don't need 5,6] 7,8,9 [don't need 10,11] 12,13,14....

Comment: Why don't you need 0 and 1? What three elements precede those two numbers? But what have you done programmatically, in JavaScript, to try to create that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through from your `start` to the `end`. Use modulus arithmetic to determine which part of the 5 number cycle the number lies on. If it's the 0th, or 1st then ignore, otherwise add them to your result:

```js
let start = 0;
let end = 20;

let result=[];
for(let i=0; i<(end-start); i++)
{
  let mod = i % 5;
  switch(mod)
  {
    case 0:
    case 1:
      // Ignore these numbers
    break
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
      result.push(start+i);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```